# left join and get the maximum datetime value

Tags: sql-server, datetime, left-join

I have two tables ,

**Table 1**

```
        Id     Name
        ===========
        1      Name1
        2      Name2
        3      Name3
```

**Table 2**

```
        Id     Tb1Id   DateTime
        =======================
        1       1      20-09-2017
        2       1      01-09-2018
        3       2      01-09-2016
        4       2      02-09-2015 
        5       3      06-09-2016 
        6       3      10-09-2019
```

I want to join those two tables by where `Table1.Id = Table2.Tb1Id` and get the maximum datetime value from Table2. The result should be like this .

```
        Id     Name     DateTime
        ========================
        1      Name1    01-09-2018
        2      Name2    01-09-2016
        3      Name3    10-09-2019
```

Comment: This looks like a simple JOIN and GROUP BY. Have you tried it? Did you encounter a problem? The only strange thing is how the dates look - date types are binary values, they have no format and SSMS displays dates formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` to avoid the confusion localized strings would create

Comment: Did you store the dates as *strings*? In this case you can't calculate the `MAX` because the localized format you used can only be sorted alphabetically. The real solution is to use a date type instead of a string. Anything else just covers up the error and will probably result in incorrect results - Is `01-09` September 1 or January 9th? Which is later, `01-09-0218` or `09-01-2018` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE(Id INT,Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 1,'Name1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Name2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Name3' 

DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE(Id INT, Tb1Id INT,[DateTime] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Table2       
SELECT 1,1,'2017-09-20' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'2018-09-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,'2016-09-01' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2,'2015-09-02' UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,3,'2016-09-06' UNION ALL 
SELECT 6,3,'2019-09-10' 

SELECT     t2.Tb1Id AS Id,
           t1.Name,
           MAX(t2.[DateTime]) AS [DateTime]
FROM @Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN @Table2 AS t2
 ON T1.Id = t2.Tb1Id
GROUP BY 
     t2.Tb1Id,
     t1.Name
```

Result

```
Id  Name        DateTime
-----------------------------------
1   Name1   2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
2   Name2   2016-09-01 00:00:00.000
3   Name3   2019-09-10 00:00:00.000
```